# Are there Amiibo costumes in Mario Kart 8 Deluxe?

Tags: amiibo, mario-kart-8-deluxe

The original Mario Kart 8 on Wii U featured several unlockable Mii costumes for scanning specific Amiibo figures. (Mario, Yoshi, Pac Man, etc)

Are these Amiibo costumes still present in Mario Kart 8 Deluxe? If so, were any new costumes added?

[image: Amiibo costumes for Mario Kart 8]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to [Nintendo](https://www.nintendo.com/amiibo/games/detail/mario-kart-8-deluxe-switch) they are still there, and that site lists the Amiibo that are compatible. [This site](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-06-02-mario-kart-8-deluxe-amiibo-mii-racing-suit-4623) breaks down which amiibo unlocks which suit.

For reference, here is the [suit list](http://amiibo.wikia.com/wiki/Mario_Kart_8) for Mario Kart 8.

Old Suits (all of Mario Kart 8's suits are present):

- Mario
- Luigi
- Peach
- Yoshi
- Donkey Kong
- Link
- Captain Falcon
- Kirby
- Samus
- Fox
- Toad
- Bowser
- Wario
- Rosalina
- Pikmin
- Animal Crossing
- Mega Man
- Pac-Man
- Sonic

New for Mario Kart 8 Deluxe:

- Splatoon